# Equivalent of Windows Postmessage for OS X C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, lazarus

I have a c++ dll for windows which pass a message to an FPC (Lazarus) application using postmessage.  It's pretty simple stuff as I'm a pretty simple guy.  It's part of an Adobe Photoshop SDK:

```
extern "C" BASICEXTERNALOBJECT_API long sendMessage(TaggedData* argv, long argc, TaggedData * retval)

{   
    // The returned value type
    retval->type = kTypeString;
    string s (argv[0].data.string);
    int i = (int)(argv[1].data.fltval); 
    retval->data.string = "Not Found";

    std::wstring stemp = s2ws(s);
        LPCWSTR win = stemp.c_str();

    HWND myApp= FindWindow(0,win);

    if (myApp != NULL){
      retval->data.string = "Found it";
      PostMessage(myApp, WM_USER + 1, i,0);

    } 
    return kESErrOK;
}
```

I'm working on making the Lazarus application work on OS X - which is working fine.  I now need to compile the above code in XCODE c++ to pass a param that would be received by the following FPC code:

```
procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TLMessage);
var
  mykey : integer;
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_MY_MESSAGE:
      begin
        mykey := Message.WParam;
        if (mykey > 0) and (mykey < 13) then
           myActionFunction(mykey);
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Could anybody point me to an example somewhere of how this would be done in Xcode?  I'm sure it's easy but Google hasn't helped me too much so far....

Answer (score 0):

Did you try opening the C++ tool in the "Command Line Utility" group? That way you can build it in C++ without having to convert it

Comment: Sorry I'm not exactly sure what you mean - I'm new to the Mac.  How does one get to the command line tool - and why would window c++ code compile in this is it doesn't compile in Xcode/

Answer (score 0):

Your existing source code are for Windows only.

`TForm1.WndProc` part code look like Delphi code and Delphi VCL framework is Windows only. No cross compiling supported.

It seems to me that only possible solution is to rewrite whole application from scratch.

Comment: No it's not Delphi.  It's FPC under Lazarus which *is* cross platform.  And like I said the Lazarus application is working fine on under OS X - including the 'delphi' code snippet above.  I can pass messages between Mac Lazarus applications without issue using PostMessage.

What I'm trying to do is to get a c++ framework that will also pass a message the same way.